# In-App Currency Purchase Detail

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working on `In-App Purchase`. I am able to get the details of a product defined in `Google Play Store` using the libraries `getSkuDetails` method.However when I do an actual purchase the price is deducted based on the address of the card registered on the wallet.

Is there any way to get the purchased `skuid` details( any ApI which can be invoked ) so that the price can be displayed on the app.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Problem statement is : Define the product in playstore as 10$.Now when I pull the details of the sku it pulls based on the phone location and displays me some price.But when actual transaction happens it deducts money based on the currency where the card is located from( by card i mean the credit card defined on the wallet).Now my question is : Is there a way ( an API) to pull the currency and the deducted amount in the purchase store?

Comment: Not that I know. getSkuDetails() returns the amount to be charged from customer in customer's currency.